# Set default image before actual image is loaded

Tags: angularjs, image, ionic-framework

In my application, several images are loaded, however when the view is opened, you can clearly see each image being loaded, by this I mean the top half of the image appears and it keeps increasing till the full image is displayed. I do not want this.

My images are inside an `ng-repeat`, what i want to do is when the page is loaded all images are set to a default image that comes bundled with the app. Now after my function has returned all new image URLs and those images have been fully loaded then they should replace the default images.

So basically like this:

1. Open view
2. Set all images to `default.jpg`
3. Get data.
4. Wait for new images to load fully.
5. Replace default images with new image URL fetched from the server.

I have never done this before and do not know how to go about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
    {{user.name}}<br>
    <img src="/images/foo/demp/default.png" actual-image="{{user.avatar}}" />
</div>
```

Then you can use a directive like:

```
myApp.directive('actualImage', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    return {
         link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
             function waitForImage(url) {
                 var tempImg = new Image();
                 tempImg.onload = function() {
                     $timeout(function() {
                         element.attr('src', url);
                     });
                 }
                 tempImg.src = url;
             }

             attrs.$observe('actualImage', function(newValue) {
                 if (newValue) {
                     waitForImage(newValue);
                 }
             });
         }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try this out. :)

Comment: Okay looks like it works, marking it as the answer, by the way if i wanted all the new images inside the ng-repeat to appear at the same time instead of one after the other how would i go about it? :)

Comment: I would like to use this outside my ng-repeat as well, for all images.

Comment: Sure, regarding the outside usage of `ng-repeat`, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Perfect! I've started reading more on directives so i understand better, thanks for your help! :)