# Waiting for angularJS image

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can I waiting to  in AngularJS  and show a default image until the directive will update the real image (that still in loading).

I need to check the image every second and not on load only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set default image before actual image is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34722000/set-default-image-before-actual-image-is-loaded)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-show="imageLoaded"><!--your image--></div>
<div ng-show="!imageLoaded"><!--default image--></div>
```

in your controller set the $scope.imageLoaded to true if your image is done loading.

Comment: but how I am checking that? how can I make sure the url is already loaded and valid?

Answer (score 0):

you should set a `<div>` with the width and the height of the image you're waiting for.

Answer (score 0):

```
Basic idea is create a directive and add it as attribute to img tag.

JS:

app.directive('imageonload', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('load', function() {
                alert('image is loaded');
            });
            element.bind('error', function(){
                alert('image could not be loaded');
            });
        }
    };
});
HTML:

 <img ng-src="{{src}}" imageonload />
```

Comment: this is good for onload  only 
how can I check it every second and stop the process while image exist